# Why am I flashing while walking?

Tags: golden-sun-dark-dawn

Sometimes when I am walking (outside of a town, on the world map), my character will flash white.

Does this mean anything? Or is it just a graphical glitch somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's those Djinns re-setting themselves. Looks like you've been putting them on quite the summoning routine.

Upon skovacs1's persuasion, I've added video documentation of this phenomenon:

After [a bit of summoning](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nNf5y0iNoM#t=210s), you'll notice at [this interval](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nNf5y0iNoM#t=341s) that the Djinns are re-setting themselves.

Comment: Summoning quite a bit, so this seems likely.

Comment: There's no probably.  It's Djinni recovering, same as the first two games.  (It's even the same sound effect!)

Comment: Since **it is Djinn recovering**, is there anyway that Derpy Hooves could mark this as the correct answer and maybe @Krazer could improve the answer by making it more conclusive. It is correct, but is phrased like an uncertainty. I'd love to see some sources for this answer, but I can't find anything aside from gameplay vids where someone uses a djinn and incidentally shortly thereafter they flash (since this doesn't confirm the answer, it isn't a source).

Comment: @skovacs1 generally asking the OP (me, in this case) to select an answer is not done - the OP is free to select the answer they feel is best.

Comment: @Shinrai this is the first Golden Sun game I ever played, so I didn't know that. Good to know :)

Comment: @DerpyHooves Fair enough. It was more of a recommendation, but I was wrong and for that I appologize. I was looking at some questions that sat for months and the OP never selected the correct answer even though in the comments, they mentioned that it answered their question and thought to remind you of this question if you'd forgotten it. Trying to look out for Krazer, I guess, but I was still in the wrong.